# Splitting a mercurial commit with renames and edits into two commits (first rename, then edit)

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension, perfarce

Is there a way I can modify the history in mercurial in order to split one commit into two separate commits?

The first of these should contain just renames/moves and the second should contain the edits. This would help with interoperability with other version control systems (e.g. perforce).

I'm hoping it's possible to automate this process with a script.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's possible
2. With manual work
3. Using MQ extension

Fist we convert commit to MQ-patch, second - split into 2 pathes, last - qfinish patches into permanent changesets

Comment: and if the history you want to edit has already been pushed, you might have a bigger problem.

Comment: @TomWillis - anonymous branch **isn't big** problem. And yes, when you rewrite history, you must know about collateral damage. I hope, OP know dark sides of changing history

Comment: Tom - I'm aware of the issues surrounding changing the history. Perhaps some background to my problem might help.

I'm using Mercurial + Perfarce plugin to interoperate with a client's perforce installation.

If I make a couple of changes locally (for example, a typical refactor where the file is moved into another directory and the namespaces at the top are edited) then when I use perfarce to push these changes I lose the version history in perforce.

To retain the history in perforce I must rename/move a file, commit, push to perforce, then edit the file, commit, and push to perforce again.